# How to reset an app's settings on Mac

Tags: macos, mac

How to reset an app's settings on Mac?
for example on GNU/Linux I just delete say `.firexox` and Firefox "Loses memory" just like it has been just installed.
I remember there was an option to clean storage on iPhone too.
But how to reset all the storage for an app in a Macbook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most app 'settings' are user data, and thus stored in the user's Library folder.

The usual files to look for are in the `Preferences` sub-folder: these are usually in the form of `com.company.appname.plist`. More complex apps might have a sub-folder with their name, and files inside.

Other places to look are in the `Application Support` sub-folder. There would then be a sub-folder with the application's name (or company's name), and files inside.

Sandboxing both complicates and simplifies things somewhat, as sandboxed apps will have all their data inside the Containers sub-folder, e.g. `~/Library/Containers/MyAppName/Data/Library/Preferences`

Simply deleting the 'MyAppName' folder will delete all the data of a sandboxed app. This is what happens on iOS, where all apps are sandboxed.

There may also be cache files inside the `Caches` sub-folder.

So-called 'cleaning' apps will do nothing more than search for files with the name of your app inside the user Library and delete them, in the hope that it's not deleting something it shouldn't, and isn't missing anything it should.

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on how the app was installed.

If it was a simple drag and drop from a disk image file, then by far the simplest method is to use something like [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (Freeware)
Drop the app onto it, then uncheck the app itself. Let it delete all the ancillary files.
This will mean at next launch, the app is 'clean'.

For any app that was installed by running an install package, you will probably need to find its uninstaller & run that to completely delete everything. Then run the installer once more.

Comment: Uninstallers don't always remove user data.